# PHP while loop and if statements into a text file

Tags: php

I'm attempting to write some data from a MySQL database into a txt file. At present I have it in a text area tag in html, but I can't seem to get it into a txt file instead. Here's what I've got as the textarea:

```
$pairresult = mysqli_query($conmysql,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_number IN ( SELECT order_number FROM orders GROUP BY order_number HAVING count(ordern_number) > 1 ) ORDER BY order_number");
echo "<h4>Customers with Multiple Orders</h4><textarea rows=\"5\" cols=\"90\" readonly>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pairresult))
  {
  echo str_replace("&","\&",$row['shipment_address_name']) . "\n";
  echo str_replace("&","\&",$row['shipment_address_street']) . "\n";
  if ( !empty($row['shipment_address_street_2']) ) {
  echo str_replace("&","\&",$row['shipment_address_street_2']) . "\n";
  } else {
  }
  echo str_replace("&","\&",$row['shipment_address_city']) . "\n";
  echo str_replace("&","\&",$row['shipment_address_postal_code']) . "\n";
  if ( !empty($row['customer_phone']) ) {
  echo str_replace("&","\&",$row['customer_phone']) . "\n";
  } else {
  }
  echo "(" . $row['fulfillment_line_item_id'] . ")\n";
  echo "[" . $row['item_name'] . "]\n\n";
  }
echo "</textarea><br />";
```

I've got a similar bit in another part of the script, but without if statements, etc. that successfully writes to a txt file:

```
$pairresult = mysqli_query($conmysql,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_number IN ( SELECT order_number FROM orders GROUP BY order_number HAVING count(order_number) > 1 ) ORDER BY order_number");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pairresult))
  {
  $multiple = "productmultiple_tracking($filetimestamp).csv";
  $handle = fopen($grouponmultiple, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$multiple);
  $data = "\"" . $row['fulfillment_line_item_id'] . "\",\"" . $row['fulfillment_line_item_id'] . "\",\"YDL\",\"\"\n";
  fwrite($handle, $data);
  fclose($handle);
    }
  echo "<a href=\"$multiple\">Download Template</a><br />";
```

How would I get that bit in the textarea to a txt file, in the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `echo` by `$data .=` in first sample, so you will have your text in $data variable. After it save $data as in the second example.

Comment: Wow! That was much easier than I was expecting! Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php
       $pdo = new PDO(...);
       $results = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM myTable INTO OUTFILE 'data.txt'");
       $dummy = $result->fetchAll();
```

The data.txt file will be written on the MySQL server. The directory must be writable by the uid of the mysqld process. It will not overwrite any existing file, and requires that you have the FILE SQL privilege.

Second alternative: use mysqldump to output to flat text file (as @OMG Ponies mentioned):

```
            mysqldump -t -T <directory> <database> <table>
```

This works like INTO OUTFILE, it needs to run on the MySQL server host, and the directory must be writable by the mysqld uid.

Third option: run query with mysql client and output text:

```
        mysql -B -e "SELECT * FROM MyTable" <database> > mytable.txt
```

This can be run on any host, and requires no special privileges or directory permissions. But NULL may not be handled as it would be with mysqldump or INTO OUTFILE.